# How to achieve MvxListView alternate row background images?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am newbie in Xamarin Android and MvvmCross and I have been trying to achieve alternate rows background for MvxListView. Below is my code for MvxListView

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:divider="@null"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/llSubtotal"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listviewitem"
android:id="@+id/mvxLVCustomerItemList" />
```

Yes, I am binding itemsource of listview from ViewModel.

Template for above Listview is ListViewItem.axml as below -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:id="@+id/lvItemTemplate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/odd">
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ivItemImage"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl StripUrl" />
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Text Title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to achieve alternate rows using custom adapter but in that case listview does not show data. Somehow I failed for it due to my lack of knowledge on Android or MvvmCross.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Please note that this project is in Xamarin and has only Android app in it. There is no UWP or other in my project this is completely Xamarin Android with MvvmCross.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what is `alternate rows`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Achieve MvxListView alternate row background images if itemsource binding from viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809679/achieve-mvxlistview-alternate-row-background-images-if-itemsource-binding-from-v)